# Intellij 13 Ultimate not able to find supported files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 13 Ultimate on Windows 7 enterprise. My maven pom includes the following:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration/>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I have settings.xml configured to access Nexus repositories within the firm for whom I am working.

Within intellij, the '2.9.1' displays in red and I see : Plugin "`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1" not found`.

At the windows command line, though, I am able to download the artifact to the local repo using the same settings.xml file and the command:

```
C:\swdtools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin>mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency
-plugin:2.1:get -DrepoUrl=https://dsnexus.uk.<HIDDEN>.<HIDDEN>:8081/nexus -Dartifact=org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1
```

Intellij doesn't pick it up if I do 'reimport all maven projects'.How to fix or debug this further within intellij?

Comment: I should add that Intellij downloads every other artifact in the pom without problem.

Comment: Have you tried a run with `mvn -X`?

Comment: Yes, to be clear there is no problem with command-line maven, it sees and installs the artifact as requested. Intellij is configured to point to the exact same settings.xml (verified right-click > maven >  open 'settings.xml'). But there's no way to do the equivalent to mvn -X *inside intellij*, is there? Problem is with intellij's integrated maven. If i comment out the <version>..</version> it no longer complains...

Comment: Compare very closely the maven environment (path to executable, where settings.xml resides) between inside and outside intellij (i.e. compare intellij settings for maven vs your command line env).

Comment: I have a (different) package underlined in red, but don't see any "not found" or other error message. Where did you see that message? I'm using IJ14 Ultimate on Ubuntu. What's weirder is that the project seems to build and run just fine. But I don't like red-underlines, especially without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue while including the report plugin "maven-jxr-plugin" with IDEA 13, but other plugins are work well.

The plugin could be found in Central Repo, but not in local.

One solution is to move the declaration from report section to build section, then the downloading will be triggered, and the reporting still works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed config intellij's config dirs in 'idea.properties' and found the 'idea' log file. The dependency problem went away as soon as I changed config dirs, no explanation, except that i didn't realize intellij was throwing errors until I ran 'idea.bat' at the command line. So - 1/ run from command line 2/ look into idea log file for unexplained problems